# Why ClassNotFoundException from sbt console but not Scala REPL

Tags: scala, sbt, classloader

First I delete the `.sbt` from my home-directory, then I make an empty project directory, and in that directory I create a `build.sbt` file:

```
echo 'ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.1.3"' > build.sbt
```

Then I run `sbt console` and at the console prompt attempt the following `Class.forname()` invocation, which produces the following `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.7.1 (Debian Java 11.0.16)
Welcome to Scala 3.1.3 (11.0.16, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
                                    
scala> Class.forName("java.sql.Connection")
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Connection
  at dotty.tools.repl.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass$$anonfun$1(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:46
```

On the other hand, if I start the REPL with the plain-old `scala` command, then invoke the same `forName()` I see this:

```
Welcome to Scala 3.1.3 (11.0.16, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
                                                                                                                            
scala> Class.forName("java.sql.Connection")
val res0: Class[?] = interface java.sql.Connection
```

So the same `forName()` invocation elicits different behavior in the `sbt` console versus the Scala REPL: a `ClassNotFoundException` in the former versus returning an instance of the `Class` class in the latter.

The sbt console also produces that `ClassNotFoundException` with any of the following lines in the `build.sbt` file:

```
classLoaderLayeringStrategy := ClassLoaderLayeringStrategy.AllLibraryJars
```

or

```
classLoaderLayeringStrategy := ClassLoaderLayeringStrategy.ScalaLibrary
```

or even

```
classLoaderLayeringStrategy := ClassLoaderLayeringStrategy.Flat
```

What is it about sbt that causes the exception, and how can sbt be made to succeed?